# Learnyounode opens always opens a file in notepad

Tags: node.js, cmd

This is a strange issue. I have installed the learnyounode module(available in nodeschool.io) to practice nodejs.After that when i type the learnyounode command a file is getting open in Notepad. It is not showing any commandline interface. Somebody please help to resolve this strange issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Basically error came due to a mistake in Path environment variable. When I gave correct path for node modules the command got executed in expected way